# symfony2 pass service to form theming

Tags: forms, symfony, service, themes

Good evenning,

I simply need to access a service from a form_theme, something like `myService.myFunction(param1, param2)` where myService is the variable which holds the service itself. The parameter I need to access is `block('form_label')` which gives me the **for** html attribute.

I tried to access myService through the `Request` by using `$request->attributes->set()` method. This worked, but not at 100%, because I need the entityManager in myService, and it was set to null. So I guess it's not the correct method.

I wanted to try with formExtensions, but I need this for many formTypes (around 10), and an extension works with only one FormType...

Is there any better solutions to access a service (with the entity manager) from my template ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass it by controller action:

```
$service = $this->get('MY_SERVICE');

...

return $this->render(..., ['service' => $service]);
```

OR use TwigExtension (without controller):

```
private $myService;

public function __construct(MyService $myService)
{
    $this->myService = $myService;
}

public function getFunctions()
{
    return [
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('my_service', [$this, 'getMyService']);
    ];
}

public function getMyService()
{
    return $this->myService;
}
```

and use it globally in templates like this:

```
{{ my_service().myDesiredMethod() }}
```

Comment: Yep ty, i figured out with the twig extension. Anyway thanks !